# Bron-Kerbosch algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, graph, igraph

I want to implement Bron-Kerbosch algorithm in igraph manually. I want to replicate the example with the graph from [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm). This is the solution I came up with so far.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.formula(1-2,1-5,5-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,4-6)
P <- as.vector(V(g))
bron_kerbosch <- function(R,P,X) {

    if (length(P) == 0 && length(X) == 0) {
        print (R)
    } else {
        for (v in P) {
            neis <- as.vector(neighbors(g,v))
            bron_kerbosch(union(R,v),intersect(P,neis),intersect(X,neis))
            P <- c(P[-which(P==v)])
            X <- c(X,v)
        }
    }
}
> bron_kerbosch(c(),P,c())
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 2 4
[1] 3 5
[1] 4 5
[1] 5 6
```

And the answer should be:
 [[1, 2, 5], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6]]
I am indexing from 1, not from 0.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't need to implement it yourself, the `max_cliques` function in `igraph` is a modified Bron-Kerbosch algorithm. It is also implemented in the Bioconductor package `RBGL`.

Comment: I would like to implement myself, and I am debugging the code. I found something interesting.
cat(1," ",neighbors(g,1),"\n")}
> 1   2 3 
So the vertex of 1 has neighbors 2,3 which is incorrect. 1 vertex' neighbors are 2,5. So I think the problem is with the neighbors function. It has some incompatibilities with my implementation

Answer (score 2):

And I've just found the solution. I used the indices of g graph, instead of names :/.
So I changed two lines:

```
 P <- V(g)$name
 neis <- neighbors(g,v)$name
```

This will work now with characters instead of numbers. And the result:

```
 [1] "1" "2" "5"
 [1] "2" "3"
 [1] "5" "4"
 [1] "3" "4"
 [1] "4" "6"
```

So the vertices are not ordered (5,4) should be (4,5) but I think it doesn't matter much. However it should be good to write this to integer numbers, instead of chars.